# Dart how to resize image height and width when its in bytes

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following code and I need a way to resize the image height and width that it in ByteData here is my code

```
Future<ByteData?> _createChartImage() async {
    var data = await _chartKey.currentState?.toImage(pixelRatio: 3.0);
    var byteData = await data!.toByteData(format: ImageByteFormat.png);
    return byteData;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't resize byte data, especially not byte data encoded in PNG format. So you have to first parse the byte data from PNG format back into a bitmap. And then resize the bitmap and then encode it back to PNG.

I would suggest taking a look at the [image](https://pub.dev/packages/image) package.

Something like the following should work:

```dart
  final image = decodePng(byteData!.buffer.asUint8List());
  final resized = copyResize(image, width: 120);
  final resizedByteData = encodePng(image);
  return ByteData.sublistView(resizedByteData);
```

Comment: I'm getting The argument type 'ByteData?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<int>'

Comment: @AlmogKoren then use `byteData!.buffer.asUint8List()`

Comment: So  have this 

final image = decodePng(byteData!.buffer.asUint8List());
    final resized = copyResize(image!, width: 1200, height: 627);
    final resizedByteData = encodePng(resized);
    return resizedByteData;

but resizedByteData is now giving me 

A value of type 'List<int>' can't be returned from the method '_createChartImage' 

Its not converting back

Comment: @AlmogKoren okay great. I've updated the answer. If it helped you solved the problem it would be nice if you could accept it.

Comment: Still not working 

The argument type 'List<int>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'TypedData'.dart(argument_type_not_assignable)
List<int> resizedByteData

Comment: Also in your code your not using resized or doing anything with it and missing null check

Comment: Can't get to work the image package isn't really that good

Comment: Yeah . Proper error checking is an exercise for the reader. I give you an answer, not finish your whole program for you.

Comment: of course, was but that is incorrect ByteData.sublistView(resizedByteData); it can't be assigned, and I couldn't find a way within the image package to convert back to bytes

Comment: basically was saying the example is wrong

Comment: @AlmogKoren What is wrong with the example? it takes your byteData, decodes the png, resizes it, encodes it and returns again a ByteData object.

Comment: It doesn't work getting this error " it can't be assigned, and I couldn't find a way within the image package to convert back to bytes "

Comment: I'm trying to find a way were I don't use the image package its not really good it blocks but is also very slow

Comment: @AlmogKoren you can simply resize it in a background isolate. why do you need a resized image in the first place?

Comment: fwiw.. imho i've answered your question. If you need help to improve performance, communicate with background isolates, or find a solution for your specific problem this seems a bit like an unrelated topic.

Comment: I solved this by first casting the ecodedPng to Uint8List........ var list = resizedByteData as Uint8List;  Then I can return as list.buffer.asUint8List()